# Displaying Groupby data with Google Charts

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I want to use Google charts(stack bar) to visualize the data, which has two string fields and one number field.
**Data->[string,string,number]**
When I try to implement the same I am getting following error
 "**All series on a given axis must be of the same data type**"

Comment: Can you post some code and the data?

Answer (score 0):

check the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#data-format) for a BarChart

only the first column may be a `'string'`